# Cassandra: How to create a UDF performing queries with volatile tables like SQL?

Tags: cassandra

I am looking for examples of UDFs in Cassandra. So far, the examples I have found are doing some computation and returning the result. I am looking for how to perform multiple database queries, store the result of some query in an intermediate table or variable. Then use the value of that variable to perform another query. Not sure how to do that. Can anyone help ?

PS: I am using the Node.js driver.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with Cassandra alone. You can do it together with Spark and push the intermediate tables back to the database.